# Replace "0" (Number) with NULL in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, transformation, pdi

How do I replace a specific value (Number or Integer) with NULL?

I ve got a number field containing "0" and I need to replace it with NULL (empty).
How do I do it with a Pentaho Data Integration step? I dont want to use javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Transformation Steps dropdown menu > Utility, "Null if..." Step.
Select the Field you want to transform and under the tab Value to turn to NULL you use "0"